# Compare Event frequency in two different data set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, frequentist, frequency

Assume we have two groups of categorical data:

- Group A: 10000 categorical events, such as Event1, Event2, Event3, ..., Event10
- Group B: 100 categorical events, same events of group A, but recorded at a different time

I need to assess the change of frequency of the events in the two groups:

- For example, Frequency of Event 1 in Group A is equal to 0.1%
- Frequency of Event 1 in Group B is 80%

how can I compare these two frequencies? is the change of frequency significant?

is the chi-squared test for homogeneity the right test to perform?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on any hypothesis testing, one can think in terms of following steps
1) State hypothesis
2) Which test to use and at what significance level

In this particular example since you are worried only about event1, you can classify as event1 and others. So, your question becomes

- Group A: 10000 categorical events, such as Event1, others
- Group B: 100 categorical events, Event1 and others

You want to assess if 10 occurrences of Event1 in Group A same as 80 occurrences of Event1 in Group B

Null hypothesis : fraction of event1 in Group A = fraction of event1 in Group B
Alternate hypothesis : fraction of event1 in Group A != fraction of event1 in Group B

Test to be used :: chi-square test for homogeneity at 0.05 level of significance

> Answering [is the chi-squared test for homogeneity the right test to
>   perform?]

Use this test only in # of observations in each of the classes >=5.

Sharing python code for same

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
contigency_table = [[10,9990],[80,20]]
stat,p,dof,expected = chi2_contingency(contigency_table)
print(p)
```

since p-value < 0.05 we reject the null hypothesis

Comment: Basically, the test that you kindly showed is telling us that the two dataset (or distributions that represent the dataset) are different, correct?

Comment: In regular working language we can say so. But going by textbook definitions (strict statistical definition) we never accept the alternative hypothesis. Either we reject the null hypothesis (which is the case here) or fail to reject the null hypothesis..